# How can I prevent misplaced new windows -top bar is hiding- in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors, window, window-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and the default Image Viewer software.

There's a strange and really frustrating case when I open an image(s) with a specific size(960x960 for today), the window will **always** appear at the top-left of my **secondary** screen with the top bar(the one we use to drag it around, I don't remember the name) hiding like this[image]
I use a pair of screens, the large as primary on the left and the small as secondary on the right. The sidebar is in the secondary screen.

What makes it strange is the other sizes like 400x400[image] or 1920x1200[image] are fine.

So my question is, is it possible to make it open in the current monitor without the top bar missing?

Comment: this is "obscure" smart window placement, which apparently does not work too well with a multi monitor setup. As a workaround to that annoyance, you may want to use Gnome Tweaks to set that windows should just open in the center of the screen by default.

Comment: I'm peeking at Gnome Tweak but can't find anything useful

Comment: Maybe it is only exposed in tweaks in later versions. A setting should be available in dconf-editor, however. Cannot check more because I do not have Gnome right now.

Comment: Relevant discussion and comments: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/246#note_474017

Comment: OK it calls `center-new-windows` and in `mutter`, takes me so long to find that. Thanks.

Comment: Is the issue only with eog (assuming that is the application )?

Comment: I only have this issue with this specific circumstance, but it alway happen though.

Comment: On the targeted monitor, is there a panel?

Comment: You can move it anywhere in Dock setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only guess what is the cause of the issue, but I have no clue of a real fix. We can however fix a bad window placement with a workaround.

#### The principle

The tiny daemon-like process will wait for creation of any window, on any of your monitors, with a ***"negative" placement*** (either x or y) on the monitor, and move it to a position of x=80px, y=80px on the corresponding monitor:

[image]

It does so by looking at the SE corner of newly created windows. SE is assumed to be the monitor it should have been fully placed on. The placement of the NW corner of the window is then the trigger to either act (move the window to a better position), or leave the window alone: it should not be at either the left or above the monitor SE is on.

In all other cases, the window is left alone completely. Note that:

- this process is not a burden in any way, it is just waiting for the occasion to happen, only acts if a new window is misplaced (not a polling process).
- I could not test it in exactly your setup, since I don't have three monitors. I don't expect any issues with it though.
- The process is scaling savvy, counts with the "translation" between Wnck and Gdk in handling scaling.

#### The code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck, Gdk

class WatchOut:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wnckscr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
        self.gdkdsp = Gdk.Display.get_default()
        self.wnckscr.connect("window_opened", self.checkonwin)
        Gtk.main()

    def actoncreate(self, window):
        wingeo = window.get_geometry();
        # get window geo, take SE as reference, abs numbers
        nw_x = wingeo.xp
        nw_y = wingeo.yp
        se_x = nw_x + wingeo.widthp
        se_y = nw_y + wingeo.heightp
        # get scale
        defmon = self.gdkdsp.get_primary_monitor()
        scale = defmon.get_scale_factor()
        # get monitor with window, gdk uses scaled(!)
        currmon = self.gdkdsp.get_monitor_at_point(se_x/scale, se_y/scale)
        # gdk uses scaled numbers!
        mongeo = currmon.get_geometry() 
        mondata = [n * scale for n in [
            mongeo.x, mongeo.y, mongeo.width, mongeo.height
        ]]
        # check if action is needed, calc in abs numbers!
        # if winx < monitorx -and/or- winy < monitory, move window
        if any([nw_x < mondata[0], nw_y < mondata[1]]):
            self.move(
                window, mondata[0] + 80, mondata[1] + 80, 700, 700
            )

    def move(self, win, x, y, w, h):
        g = Wnck.WindowGravity.NORTHWEST
        flags = Wnck.WindowMoveResizeMask.X | \
            Wnck.WindowMoveResizeMask.Y | \
            Wnck.WindowMoveResizeMask.WIDTH | \
            Wnck.WindowMoveResizeMask.HEIGHT
        win.set_geometry(g, flags, x, y, w, h)

    def checkonwin(self, scr, newwin):
        if newwin.get_window_type () == Wnck.WindowType.NORMAL:
            self.actoncreate(newwin)

WatchOut()
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the code above into an empty file, save it as `watchout.py`
2. Test-run it from a terminal by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/watchout.py
   ```

   Try to open application with a misbehaving placement, which should be pretty predictable, looking at your question.
3. If all works fine, add it to startup applications. Possibly you need to set a tiny break before starting up the process, to make sure it won't break on a uncompleted desktop-loading.

Comment: hmm..whats the diff between Wnck.Screen and Gdk.Display? Are they both interfaces to the window manager?

Answer (score 1):

There have been problems reported where windows are cropped when the two monitors don't line up at the top:

[image: screen display.png]

To confirm they line up perfectly along the top use `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr | grep " connected" | grep "+0"

HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

The `+0` confirms both monitors are aligned to the top.

Comment: I move them on purpose to match their actual position.

Comment: I understand that. And it has worked for me being non-aligned in Ubuntu 16.04 Unity. However there are reports of cropping under newer versions / desktops. Hopefully that bug will be fixed soon. In the mean time you can use `Alt`+`F7` to quickly move the window with the mouse.

Comment: Yeah, but that still slow as I have to check so many neural network output. It appearing in second screen took a bit but of time to move but accumulating them lead to a good bit of time though. Now I use centered new windows when doing something like this but smart placement(if it doesn't bug) is way better.

Comment: Something else to consider is some programs let you specify window coordinates to open at. It's called the `geometry` option. I use this on startup to get my applications' windows setup on three monitors the way I like.

Comment: Will it open multiple windows at the same place like centered?

Comment: No I don't usually use "centered" to open windows. With my three monitor setup there is no "center" position. For example my terminal opens with: `gnome-terminal --geometry=92x30+4644+1204` in startup applications.